# Python Random String Sha256 Hasher

Tags: python, random, sha256

I wanted to create a python program that first takes a input (which is a sha256hash) named *inputhash*. Then takes numbers 0 to 9 and letters a to z (which is 36 total options)and rearranges them in 32 spots and saves it into a str variable, lets say its *randomstring*. Then chooses a random number(lets say its called *correctnumber*) from 0 to 99 and places that number at the end of *randomstring*. Finally it hashes(sha256) *randomstring* and if it doesnt match *inputhash* it repeats the process till it does. When it finally does it prints the variable *correctnumber*. How do you create this?

This is how you sha256 hash

```
import hashlib
var = 'password'
hashedWord = hashlib.sha256(var.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
```

But I have know idea on the other features. Thanks

THIS DOESNT HAVE TO BE IN PYTHON. If another language is easier/better do that language.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in this question. Also, please post your code. We will not write the whole program for you.

Comment: You want to write a bruteforcer? I don't think random is the best choice for this, it can take forever. Why don't you use `itertools.permutations` in a generator?

Comment: @t.m.adam do you have any idea how this would be done

Comment: Is `inputhash` guaranteed to end in a number 0-99? Could it contain repeating characters? Does it have random or fixed size, and If so, how many characters? If the size is unknown or too large, this process will be very stressing for your cpu.

Comment: @t.m.adam input hash is any digit from 0 to 99. If it’s any easier it is 2 digits. Otherwise it can be 1 or 2

Comment: Then why you do you nead a-z characters?

Comment: @t.m.adam A to Z characters is for the variable randomstring which chooses 32 characters out of the 26 letters and 10 numbers 0 to 9. Inputhash is a completely different variable that chooses a number from 0 to 99 and “adds” it to the end of randomstring. So randomstring is now randomstringinputhash or a completely new variable that’s has the input hash number on the end of randomstring

Comment: @t.m.adam do you know how to do this. If you can provide very helpful information or do it I can offer quite a bit of money

Comment: Sorry, i don't offer services, and i don't think that you should pay anyone for this task - except if you have no knowledge of Python, in which case you could just study some online tutorials.

Comment: Now, about your question, i'm afraid i lost you. `inputhash` is the hash value of a number 0-99 right? For example, `inputhash` is `hashlib.sha256('10'.encode()).hexdigest()`. if you want to guess that value, all you have to do loop over `range(100)`, hash and compare the digests.

Comment: @t.m.adam sorry for the confusion. In all of my comments I mixed up the variables. I confused input hash with correct number. Inputhash is actually a predetermined hash value. Which is randomstring and correctnumber added on the end. The point of the program is to have a user input a hash which is a real sha256 hash then it goes through the process of selecting randomstring and correctnumber and hashing it then comparing that with inputhash. If it doesn’t match it repeats the steps. If it does it simply prints correctnumber. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @t.m.adam everything in the original question is correct

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, do you know if the random string has a fixed or random size? Could it contain repeating characters? If it does you'll have to use `itertools.product`. Is it alphanumeric? If it is, and has random size, how can you be sure of the correct number? For example, if the random string is 'abc1' and the number is '2' (so `inputhash` is the hash value of 'abc12'), how would you know if the correct number is '2' or '12'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164520/discussion-between-user9123-and-t-m-adam).

Comment: Note that you are generating up to 6334028666297327770616228694681188660989646182809600 different combinations (32 digits and letters plus 2 digits is 36 ^ 32 * 100). Even if you could generate a billion combinations *per second*, that would take you 200850731427490099271189392905923029 years to complete (that's a number with 36 digits). The universe doesn't last that long.

Comment: Even if you used all the computers in the world to try to generate those combinations, you *could not ever hope to bruteforce the hash*. There is no point in even trying.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to bruteforce a SHA256 hash with a character set of 32 lower alphanumeric characters, plus one or two digits. If so, this code is unlikely to solve your problem, (it's practically impossible, and python is a very bad choice for this task) but it may give you some ideas.

You can create all the possible character combinations with `itertools.product()` and produce them with a generator, so it won't have a big inpact on memory.

```
def string_generator(size=32):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    for i in itertools.product(chars, repeat=size):
        yield i
```

Now we can iterate over the items in that generator and for each item append a digit in `range(100)` to create possible matches. If the hash of a possible match equals the input hash, congrats you've found the correct number!

The complete code:

```
import string
import itertools
import hashlib

def string_generator(size=32):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    for i in itertools.product(chars, repeat=size):
        yield ''.join(i)

def bruteforce(hash):
    possible_strings = string_generator()
    for i in possible_strings:
        for n in range(100):
            s = i + str(n)
            print('\r' + s, end=' ')
            if hashlib.sha256(s.encode('ascii')).hexdigest() == hash:
                print('\rHash found: ' + s)
                return n 
    print('\nNot found.') 

s = bruteforce('my hash')
```